# Hot to loop through XML file and create php array that consists all xml tags in the file

Tags: php, xml

I want to create a php array with all xml tags in a remote XML file. The depth and structure of the XML file will be unknown, so that's why maybe recursive function will be the best solution. Anyway, I will add a sample just for the case of study. Here is my code so far:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('https://sxy.bg/test.xml');

$xml   = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

the xml in the file is:

```
$xml = '<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title name="product">Test Store</title>
<link type="url">https://www.sxy.bg/</link>
<description encoding="utf-8">SXY</description>
<item>
<g:id>8797</g:id>
<g:title>Product Title 8797</g:title>
<g:description>Product description 8797</g:description>
<g:link>https://www.sxy.bg/store/8797</g:link>
<g:image_link>https://www.sxy.bg/images/store/8797.jpg</g:image_link>
<g:brand>Olight</g:brand>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:price>99.00 EUR</g:price>
<g:shipping>
<g:country>BG</g:country>
<g:service>Standard</g:service>
<g:price>4.95 EUR</g:price>
</g:shipping>
<g:google_product_category>Auto</g:google_product_category>
<g:custom_label_0>Hot Offers</g:custom_label_0>
</item>
<item>
<g:id>8813</g:id>
<g:title>Product Title 8813</g:title>
<g:description>Product description 8813</g:description>
<g:link>https://www.sxy.bg/store/8813</g:link>
<g:image_link>https://www.sxy.bg/images/store/8813.jpg</g:image_link>
<g:brand>Olight</g:brand>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:price>305.00 EUR</g:price>
<g:shipping>
<g:country>BG</g:country>
<g:service>Standard</g:service>
<g:price>4.95 EUR</g:price>
</g:shipping>
<g:google_product_category>Auto</g:google_product_category>
<g:custom_label_0>Hot Offers</g:custom_label_0>
</item>
<item>
<g:id>8809</g:id>
<g:title>Product Title 8809</g:title>
<g:description>Product description 8809</g:description>
<g:link>https://www.sxy.bg/store/8809</g:link>
<g:image_link>https://www.sxy.bg/images/store/8809.jpg</g:image_link>
<g:brand>Olight</g:brand>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:price>375.00 EUR</g:price>
<g:shipping>
<g:country>BG</g:country>
<g:service>Standard</g:service>
<g:price>4.95 EUR</g:price>
</g:shipping>
<g:google_product_category>Auto</g:google_product_category>
<g:custom_label_0>Hot Offers</g:custom_label_0>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>';
```

The desired array format is:

```
array("channel", "title", "Link","description", "item", "g:id","g:title", "g:description","g:link","g:image_link","g:brand","g:condition", "g:availability","g:price","g:shipping","g:country","g:service","g:google_product_category","g:custom_label_0");
```

The array should consist only unique tags.. What would be the best approach for the task?
Thanks for your time

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I first started by looping through the XML but than discovered that the depth of the xml file will vary so "pure" looping would not be working , and I am not familar with the recursion.. For example <g:shipping> has nodes, in some cases some of them may have nodes too..

Comment: You said that 'the array should consist only unique tags' but your desired array contains 'g:price' twice.  Please clarify

Comment: Sorry, Copy/Paste typo

Comment: If you were to [use a recursiveDOMIterator](https://github.com/salathe/spl-examples/wiki/RecursiveDOMIterator) with a global array to store tags your task would become quite simple

Comment: Your sample xml isn't well formed; it's missing the namespace declarations. Please edit and fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want all the unique tag names, you could just use a simple regex

```
$numTags = preg_match_all('|<([^/>\s]+)|', $xml, $matches);
$tagNames = array_unique($matches[1]);
```

Comment: You are Magician Rob! With 2 Lines of code?! Wow 
Thank you!

Comment: is it possible to remove tag attributes from xml tags with this code? How if it is possible? Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised that you're seeing attributes turn up using this code.  Please can you share an example?

Comment: if you try this you will see that tags comes with attributes:
$xml = file_get_contents(urldecode('http://armybg.com/module.php?ModuleName=com.summercart.products_feed&ProductsFeedKey=kjKJhdJKkhgJH&LanguageCode=BG&CurrencyCode=BGN'));
$numTags = preg_match_all('|<([^/>]+)>|', $xml, $matches);
$tagNames = array_unique($matches[1]);
var_dump($tagNames);

Comment: Hmm, can you share a source code fragment, rather than a URL?  At a guess, it could be that the tag name and attribute are separated by a newline rather than a space.  I have amended the answer to deal with this

Comment: Actualy that's all the code I am using to parse the xml. When I copy xml as string the attributes don't show but when load the xml from url than they show. I tested the url for xml validation but the online tool confirmed the xml is valid.. It's strange.. Also I tried to load the xml other way than using file_get_contents like this:
$xml = simplexml_load_file(urldecode('http://armybg.com/module.php?ModuleName=com.summercart.products_feed&ProductsFeedKey=kjKJhdJKkhgJH&LanguageCode=BG&CurrencyCode=BGN')); but doen's work either..

Comment: The edited code fix the attributes issue ! Thanks for your time!